# Objective-C Import

Tags: objective-c, import, header

What is the difference between:

```
#import "foo.h"
```

and:

```
#import <foo.h>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#import "foo.h"` is normally used for headers of your project.

`#import <foo.h>` are headers of frameworks you link to.

Comment: While this is generally the case, I believe the technical answer is the directory in which the compiler looks for the header file. Quotes has it look in the same directory as the source code, while <> have it look in the standard framework directories.

Comment: Actually, it's even a little more complex than that. GCC allows you to specify which directories are searched for <> or "" includes.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Directory-Options.html